# Query to return rows with consecutive dates based on todays date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following problem to solve. I have a table in SQL Server 2008 which has the following columns:

```
Person, JobType, ShiftDate, Hours
```

I need to extract anyone who has worked (or is scheduled to work) over 7 consecutive shifts (OR anyone who has worked or is scheduled to work over 52 hours) with today being my start point.

**NOTE**: people can work more than 1 shift per day. So, I have a query which selects 7 days prior to today and 7 days in the future:

```
t1.Starton BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(DAY, 7, GETDATE())
```

My thoughts are that if I can select any consecutive date ranges with today being "in the middle" that would at least give me a start point (as any dates missing are assumed to be rest days and don't count)? I have seen various posts on SO which show how to get consecutive date ranges from a table but I don't know how to make them with today being the start point. Any help or indeed suggestions of a better way of doing this would be very gratefully received.

Comment: . . Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Wow...lightening fast response.....

Comment: if you make a date table, then for any shift, select all the next seven days inclusive of date of the object shift, then select on EXISTS(SELECT Shift on DateTableDate) and see if there are seven of them

Comment: Sample data is as follows: Person JobType ShiftDate Hours
Mike Ast 28/08/2018 7.5
Mike Ast 29/08/2018 7.5
Mike Ast 30/08/2018 7.5
Mike Ast 31/08/2018 7.5
Mike Ast 01/09/2018 7.5
Mike Ast 02/09/2018 7.5
Mike Ast 03/09/2018 7.5
Mike Ast 04/09/2018 7.5
Dave Help 29/08/2018 7
Dave Help 31/08/2018 7
Dave Help 01/09/2018 5
Pam Cook 26/08/2018 8
Pam Cook 28/08/2018 8
Pam Cook 30/08/2018 8
Pam Cook 01/09/2018 8
Pam Cook 02/09/2018 8
Pam Cook 03/09/2018 8
Pam Cook 05/09/2018 8
Pam Cook 06/09/2018 8
Pam Cook 07/09/2018 8

Comment: With today being the 31/08/2018....the result would only return Mike's shifts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to find those that have at least 7 continues days within last & next week.

You can rank per group of continues days for each person.
Then count the days per person and dategroup.

Once you have that, just select the persons that have a dategroup with 7 or more days in them.

For example, this test snippet:

```
--
-- Using a table variable for easy testing
--
declare @ShiftTable table (Person varchar(30), JobType varchar(8), ShiftDate datetime, [Hours] decimal(5,2));
--
-- Sample Data
--
insert into @ShiftTable (Person, JobType, ShiftDate, [Hours]) values
('Mike','Ast',GetDate()-5,7.5),('Mike','Ast',GetDate()-4,7.5),
('Mike','Ast',GetDate()-3,7.5),('Mike','Ast',GetDate()-2,7.5),('Mike','Ast',GetDate()-1,7.5),('Mike','Ast',GetDate(),7.5),('Mike','Ast',GetDate()+1,7.5),('Mike','Ast',GetDate()+2,7.5),
('Dave','Help',GetDate()-2,7),('Dave','Help',GetDate()-1,7),('Dave','Help',GetDate(),5),
('Pam','Cook',GetDate()-6,8),('Pam','Cook',GetDate()-6,8),('Pam','Cook',GetDate()-4.2,3),('Pam','Cook',GetDate()-4,5),
('Pam','Cook',GetDate()-3.2,4),('Pam','Cook',GetDate()-3,3),('Pam','Cook',GetDate()-2,8),('Pam','Cook',GetDate()-1,8),
('Pam','Cook',GetDate(),8),('Pam','Cook',GetDate()+1,8),('Pam','Cook',GetDate()+3,8);

--
-- Query
--
SELECT DISTINCT Person
FROM
(
    SELECT Person, DateGroup, COUNT(*) AS TotalDays
    -- , MIN(ShiftDate) as MinShiftDate, MAX(ShiftDate) as MaxShiftDate
    FROM
    (
      SELECT Person, CAST(ShiftDate AS DATE) AS ShiftDate,
       DATEADD(day, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Person ORDER BY Person, CAST(ShiftDate AS DATE) DESC)-1, CAST(ShiftDate AS DATE)) as DateGroup
      FROM @ShiftTable
      WHERE CAST(ShiftDate AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-6,GETDATE()) AS DATE) AND CAST(GETDATE()+6 AS DATE)
      GROUP BY Person, CAST(ShiftDate AS DATE)
    ) q1
    GROUP BY Person, DateGroup
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 7
) q2
ORDER BY Person;
```

Returns:

```
Person
------
Mike
```

Comment: Cracking Mike....thank-you...I will give this a go over the weekend and report back

Comment: @JohnC You might wanna change the range of -6/+6, or not.  I just thought it was more accurate if you wanted to select previous and next week based on the current date.  It's just a sample after all.

Comment: Hey LukStorms.....that is fantastic. Thank-you for taking the time to help me out

Comment: Just one more question please - I have adapted your code to suit my existing SQL table. I would now like to add some other fields to my query. My original table is called SiteShift. I have a LEFT OUTER JOIN to Personnel t6 ON t1.Person = t6.Oid. I would like to include t6.Name in my output. Can you help me please? I am a bit of a beginner at this but if you could show me an example I am sure I can figure the rest out. Thanks in advance JC

Comment: @JohnC  Just add the `LEFT JOIN` after the `FROM` for the shifttable. Then add something like a `MAX(t6.Name) AS Name` in that select of the q1 and q2 sub-queries.  And lastely, add `Name` to the select of the outer query.  I'm just suggesting to use MAX, because then you don't have to add `Name` to the group by's.

Comment: @JohnC On second thought, it's easier to simply add the `LEFT JOIN` to the `q2` subquery.  And then select the name also.

Answer (score 1):

```
 --build a date table (you should build a permanent one)

select * into #DateTable from (SELECT dateadd(day,row_number() over (order by a1.name), cast('20180101' as date)) adate from sys.objects a1 cross join sys.objects b ) dq where dq.adate < '20220101'

--make some sample data

SELECT dq.* into #shifts from
(
select 1 as empid, cast('20180901 10:00:00' as datetime2) as starton, cast('20180901 12:00:00' as datetime2) as endOn
union
select 1 as empid, cast('20180902 10:00:00' as datetime2) as starton, cast('20180902 12:00:00' as datetime2) as endOn
union
select 1 as empid, cast('20180903 10:00:00' as datetime2) as starton, cast('20180903 12:00:00' as datetime2) as endOn
union
select 1 as empid, cast('20180904 10:00:00' as datetime2) as starton, cast('20180904 12:00:00' as datetime2) as endOn
union
select 1 as empid, cast('20180904 15:00:00' as datetime2) as starton, cast('20180904 19:00:00' as datetime2) as endOn
union
select 1 as empid, cast('20180905 10:00:00' as datetime2) as starton, cast('20180905 12:00:00' as datetime2) as endOn
union
select 1 as empid, cast('20180906 10:00:00' as datetime2) as starton, cast('20180906 12:00:00' as datetime2) as endOn
union
select 1 as empid, cast('20180907 10:00:00' as datetime2) as starton, cast('20180907 12:00:00' as datetime2) as endOn
union
select 1 as empid, cast('20180908 10:00:00' as datetime2) as starton, cast('20180908 12:00:00' as datetime2) as endOn
union
select 1 as empid, cast('20180910 10:00:00' as datetime2) as starton, cast('20180908 12:00:00' as datetime2) as endOn
union
select 1 as empid, cast('20180911 10:00:00' as datetime2) as starton, cast('20180908 12:00:00' as datetime2) as endOn
union
select 1 as empid, cast('20180912 10:00:00' as datetime2) as starton, cast('20180908 12:00:00' as datetime2) as endOn
union
select 1 as empid, cast('20180913 10:00:00' as datetime2) as starton, cast('20180908 12:00:00' as datetime2) as endOn
union
select 1 as empid, cast('20180914 10:00:00' as datetime2) as starton, cast('20180908 12:00:00' as datetime2) as endOn
union
select 1 as empid, cast('20180915 10:00:00' as datetime2) as starton, cast('20180908 12:00:00' as datetime2) as endOn
union
select 1 as empid, cast('20180916 10:00:00' as datetime2) as starton, cast('20180908 12:00:00' as datetime2) as endOn
union
select 1 as empid, cast('20180917 0:00:00' as datetime2) as starton, cast('20180908 12:00:00' as datetime2) as endOn
union
select 1 as empid, cast('20180919 10:00:00' as datetime2) as starton, cast('20180908 12:00:00' as datetime2) as endOn
union
select 1 as empid, cast('20180919 10:00:00' as datetime2) as starton, cast('20180908 12:00:00' as datetime2) as endOn




) dq;


 --here is the query - find days that are followed by 6 days with shifts in the next 6 days (so shifts that are part of a 7 day run)

SELECT IQ.empid, IQ.starton dayFollowedBy6Shifts from 
(
select s.empid,CASt(s.starton as date) starton, cast(s2.starton as date) starton2 from #shifts s join #DateTable d on  DATEDIFF(DAY, s.starton, d.adate) < 7 and d.adate >= CAST(s.starton as date) join #shifts s2 on  s2.empid = s.empid and cast(s2.starton as date) = d.adate
  Group by s.empid, CASt(s.starton as date), cast(s2.starton as date)

) IQ 
group by IQ.empid,IQ.starton having COUNT(0) >= 7




drop table #datetable;
drop table #shifts;
```